# Could I define my own method to calculate UserSimilarity in Mahout's collaborative filtering?

Tags: mahout, similarity, collaborative-filtering

I am using Apache Mahout's user-based collaborative filtering for recommender systems.

I have two questions.

1) Must the UserID and ItemID be numeric?

My datamodel looks like this:

jessestay,e/4d0b55757114464eb56cdf01bf5d6842,1

where "jessestay" is userID, "e/4d0b55757114464eb56cdf01bf5d6842" is itemID, "1" is the preference value from user to this item.

How could I encode the userID and ItemID to int or long?

2) When I am using UserSimilarity, must I use the built Euclidean Distance, Pearson Correlation Coefficient, or Spearman Correlation?

Could I define my own method to estimate userSimilarity?

This is my first time to use Apache Mahout's collaborative filtering.

Thank you very much for your help.
Looking forward to your reply!

xiao shen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user and item ID must be numeric. Just hash your values to longs. The only catch is that you have to remember the mapping to map back to strings. If you also have numeric IDs, it's better to use them.

Yes, just implement `UserSimilarity` to define whatever similarity you want.